# Query array of maps in Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

How can I fetch all map values added in an array using cloud firestore. The data is structured as:
**collection->documents->subcollection->document->array[{key:"someValue",key:"someValue2"},{key:"someValue",key:"someValue2"}]**

[image: Image for reference]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch all the seat values once you can perform a [simple `get()` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document), then return the `doc.data()`'s `.seats` array or filter for seats from that data.

If you want to listen for realtime changes to the `seats` array you should create an [`onSnapshot` listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) where you can read and handle creations, updates, and deletions to the `doc.data()`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. This gives me an idea to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear.  Are you trying to fetch the *entire* array?  In which case, fetch the document; the field 'seats' has the entire array.

Are you trying to search for a specific entry/map in the array?  Simple answer: don't.  The various ways of matching array entries *all* require *exact* match of the *entire* array element. (i.e., matching your `'1'` element would require `{seat: "S2", selected: false}` to match - you can't match just on `"S2"`.

So when I say "don't", I mean structure your data differently.  A general requirement of NoSQL and Firestore is to think about your queries *first*, and structure your data to allow for the queries you need.  A "logical, compact structure" is often the *wrong* approach in NoSQL.

Comment: I actually want to fetch all the seats available in that particular array.